# What should I choose Session Save - 'Files' or 'DB' while magento install?

Tags: magento2, session, install

I have to choose **Session Save - 'Files' or 'DB'** while installing Magento2

What is different, advantage, disadvantage?

What should I choose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained pretty nice in the Magento Devdocs (actually the functionality is the same as in Magento 1):

> In the Session Storage Options section, click one of the following
> options:
>
> **File** to store user session data on the file system in the
> `[your Magento install dir]/var/session` directory. File-based session
> storage is appropriate unless the Magento file system access is slow
> or you have a clustered database.
>
> **Database** to store user session data
> in the database. Choose database storage if you have a clustered
> database; otherwise, there might not be much benefit over file-based
> storage.

See here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html

Comment: I wanted to add we've tested and seen a degradation of performance of using database in non-clustered environment on many lower end hosting environments so would recommend using file system for those cases.

Comment: NB Mag2 sessions are not stored in de app tree but under the default PHP session.save_path (usually `/var/lib/php5/sessions`).

Answer (score 4):

**DB**

session storage in database is  better for security but add additional load to database.

**Files**

session storage that uses file system allow easy access to session information via ftp.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion MySQL is not really a good solution for storing the session data in it since it can slow down your database also it can grow huge.

Either way: Don't forget to set up the cleaning for the sessions because they can take up quite a big space after a while.

Answer (score 0):

We should use Redis for our site.

1) Reduce stress to the website database.

2) https://redis.io/topics/introduction