# var/session folder was too many files so site not work

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9 var/session folder is full 2.5 million files are there, so the site is not working,
if I remove some files from the session folder, the site is working for a few hrs, but after it was stuck,
what is the alternate solution for this, rather than remove the session folders file?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a cron job to delete session files older than 7 days

```
find /magento/var/session/sess* -type f -ctime +7 -exec rm -- {} \;
```

Comment: i hvae find other way like changes in loca.xml file Change:

<session_save>file</session_save>

To:

<session_save>db</session_save>

Comment: is this are ok or not?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93495/what-should-i-choose-session-save-files-or-db-while-magento-install